# MacOS How to do ⌘+\ shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-drive, google-docs

I'm new to MacOS and need to work on *Google Doc*, I often use the *'Clear Formatting'* KeyBoard Shortcut which is `ALT+SPACE` on *Windows*. But `⌘+SPACE` doesn't work on *Google Doc* and an alternative seems to be `⌘+\`. But an antislash isn't directly accessible on my keyboard, I need to do : `OPTION+SHIFT+/`.

My keyboard looks like this one (not sure if Belgian or French):
[image]

Comment: In the other comment you made, you tried `command + option + /` and that didn't clear the text formatting?

Comment: I tried almort everything : (

Comment: If you've tried many things, then the keyboard shortcut is probably not supported with your keyboard format. If you'd like, this could be migrated to [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). Maybe someone there would have a solution. I haven't been able to find anything on Google that is helpful for an AZERTY layout.

Comment: Instead of worrying about the shortcut at the moment, have you identified the keyboard combo to produce a backslash? According to one thing I found, a \ is made with `option + shift + /`. The next step would be to try and combine `option + shift + command + /` to see if that does anything.

Comment: of course I tried these kind of obvious things. Well I'm assuming it's not possible

Comment: Google states on their [document page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) that not all shortcuts are supported with all languages or keyboard formats. So you can keep trying, but it may not be possible. You could also follow the steps in this post to [submit a feature request](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm08yUZumW5z7w/?hl=en)